# How can I load CPLEX libraries in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, cplex

I'm working on an optimization problem and was recommended to use IBM ILOG CPLEX. I have finally created my CPLEX model, but I need to integrate it with an existing C# app. How do I load the CPLEX libraries in Visual Studio?

This is for a C# app that loads data from an Excel file, and will feed data into the CPLEX model and receive the decision variable from the CPLEX model.

I expect to be able to load the CPLEX libraries in Visual Studio and then follow the tutorials on how to use the model

Comment: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21400073 & https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.5.1/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/Examples/topics/exampleCsharpDotNet.html

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/GettingStarted/topics/tutorials/Csharp/Csharp_synopsis.html

Comment: I found these and there are other example .cs files that come with the installation. But I’m having a hard time referencing to CPLEX. For example, the example code has “using ILOG.Concert;” and “using ILOG.CPLEX;”. How can I add reference to ILOG?

Comment: Never mind, I saw found .csproj sample projects that already have the reference. I might just copy that project and edit it out. Thanks though. :)

Comment: Never mind, I found .csproj sample projects that already have the reference. I might just copy that project and edit it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CPLEX installation has a file called `dotnet.html` that contains step-by-step instructions about how to setup a project in C# with CPLEX. And then you have the tutorial in the user manual: [ILOG CPLEX Optimization Studio > CPLEX > Getting Started with CPLEX > Tutorials > .NET tutorial](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/GettingStarted/topics/tutorials/Csharp/Csharp_synopsis.html)